# Изменить идентификаторы устройств компьютера

Tags: железо, эмулятор

Есть программа, которая работает в демо режиме 30 дней, затем перестает. Программа проверяет лицензию через интернет. Смена windows, id жёсткого диска и сетевой карты не помогли. Есть ли способы сменить или эмулировать другой идентификатор материнский платы, процессора и остальных компонентов?

Comment: Так проще сделать реверс инженеринг самого приложения и написать кряк (варианты: замена dll, эмуляция сервера). Для этого надо разобрать, что и куда отсылает приложение, если не получится, то дизассемблировать бинарники.

Comment: Ну первое, что можно сказать - видимо, не зря программа является платной =) Второе - то что вы пытаетесь сделать является нарушением, так что "на свой страх и риск". Как насчет виртуальной машины (хотя шансы маловаты)?

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно знать что и как программа получает.